# Cannot get html attribute using PHP Simple Html DOM

Tags: php

I am tryng to get the ,,sold" info from eBay listing- https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Box-With-Tail-Pipe-Rear-Back-Silencer-Fits-Citroen-C2-C3-I-C3-Pluriel-GCN499/254292997729?hash=item3b350b3661:g:clEAAOSwnhldLB4J.
Here is the screenshot:
[image]

As you can see I want to get ,1 sold" text on the upper right corner of the screen. I am using the class ,,vi-txt-underline" to get it, however it is not working. Does anyone know how this can be done, using other attribute or something different? Here is the code:

```
            $sold = $html->find(".vi-text-underline", 0);

            if($sold != null){
                $item['sold'] = $sold->find("a", 0)->plaintext;
            }else{
                $item['sold'] = '';



   ["tag"]=>
      string(4) "text"
      ["attr"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["children"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["nodes"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["parent"]=>
      *RECURSION*
      ["_"]=>
      array(1) {
        [4]=>
        string(6) "1 sold"
```

The above is part of the debugged `$sold` variable.

I am using an array $item[] because I am also searching  for more info before this part of the code.

Comment: It's possible that this information is being added through a javascript call after the page loads, in which case reading the static HTML of the rendered page may not be sufficient to get this information. What result are you currently getting with this approach?

Comment: I made `var dump` on the `$sold' variable and on the above section is part of the result. I want to find a way to get the text "1 sold" because clearly with finding the anchor is not the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. get page contents

   $url = "https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Box-With-Tail-Pipe-Rear-Back-Silencer-Fits-Citroen-C2-C3-I-C3-Pluriel-GCN499/254292997729?hash=item3b350b3661:g:clEAAOSwnhldLB4J";

   $content = file_get_contents($url);
2. find what you want

   echo strpos($content,'1 sold');

Comment: This is nice, but I have already got the content in other way and put the whole html in an array. The only way to get the info is by html attribute. I only have the class above, not a div element.

Comment: Can you inspect the element to see which is the right path to use?

Comment: `$sold->find("a", 0)->plaintext;` instead ofthis, the new code has to complete the following rule: [4]=>
        string(6) "1 sold"